# Let $f(x) = x^5 + 4x^3 + 8x^2 + 32$ be a polynomial. Given that $f(2i) = 0$, express $f(x)$ as a product of linear complex polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm reviewing for my exam and I have a few questions about this solution.

The given polynomial $f(x)$ has only real coefficients. Therefore, given $x = 2i$ is a root of $f(x)$, by the Conjugate Roots Theorem (CJRT), $x = −2i$ must also be a root of $f(x)$.

By the Factor Theorem (FT), therefore we have two linear factors: $(x − 2i)$ and $(x + 2i)$. Multiplying these two factors gives us:

$$(x−2i)(x+2i)=(x^2 −2\operatorname{Re}(2i)x+|2i|^2)=(x^2 + 4)$$
 as a quadratic factor of $f(x)$.
Then by long division, we get $f(x)=(x^2 +4)·(x^3 +8)$.
The roots of $(x^3 +8)$ can be obtained using the Complex Nth Roots Theorem (CNRT).
￼First, in polar form,
Then, the cubic roots of $−8$ are given by $−8 = 8 [\cos (\pi) + i \sin (\pi)]$ .

Why does $(x^2 −2\operatorname{Re}(2i)x+|2i|^2)$ become $x^2+4$? What happened to the $-2\operatorname{Re}(2i)x$?

And where did the $-8 = 8 [\cos (\pi) + i \sin (\pi)]$ come from?

Comment: Recall that $z\cdot \bar{z} = 2 \Re(z)$. Since $2i$ is purely imaginary, it has a real part of $0$.The other part can be answered by $-1 = e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(2\pi)$

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{Re}(z)$ is the real part of complex number $z=x+iy$, in other words: $\operatorname{Re}(z)=x$

For the second question:

Notice that $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$, there for we can write $8$ as

$$-8 = 8 [\cos (\pi) + i \sin (\pi)]$$

Comment: What does Re(2i) equal on the real part? Would that equal 0?

Comment: Oh nevermind I get it.

Comment: For my second question, I was wondering why you would put -8 in the polar form? what's the purpose of it?

Comment: The purpose for that is to solve the equation $x^3=-8$, (or: finding the roots, if you wish). How its done? You can find it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula
(you may jump to 'Applications')